# Karatzas, Ioannis & Shreve, Steven E. , "Methods of mathematical finance", Example 1.2.3, "Doubling Strategy"

Tags: probability-theory, finance

I'm reading the first chapter of Methods of mathematical finance from Karatzas as part of my B.Sc-thesis in mathematics and I don't understand 1 argument in example 2.3 of Chapter 1: The author defines the stochastic integral on [0,T),

$I(t) := $$\int_0^t \sqrt{\frac{1}{T-u}} d W(u) $

with W(.) is a 1-dimensional Brownian Motion and can (apparently) easily conclude that I(t) is a martingal on [0,T); but I cannot...

I can show that it is a local martingal on [0,T) 
(for example with : Philip E. Protter. Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations, III.5, Theo 17 : 
\sqrt{\frac{1}{T-u}} is continous and the Brownian Motion W is a local martingal and therefore I is a local martingale)

I've tried many things, we can't use:

1.)Bounded local martingals are martingals, because I isn't bounded.

2.)Stochastic integrals with bounded integrand are martingals, because the integrand $\sqrt{\frac{1}{T-u}}$ isn't bounded for $u\ge T$

Please help, 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to prove, exactly?

Comment: Hello @Math1000, thanks for your effort to get a proper answer for me (conversation with @Gordon)^^ Problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say that $I$ is a martingale on $[0,T)$ is to say that $E[I(t)|\mathcal F_s]=I(s)$ for all $0\le s<t<T$; equivalently, $\{I(t):0\le t\le t_0\}$ is a martingale for each $t_0\in(0,T)$. But for fixed $t_0\in(0,T)$, the (deterministic) integrand $u\mapsto 1/\sqrt{T-u}$ is continuous and bounded on $[0,t_0]$. Consequently the stochastic integral $I(t)$, $0\le t\le t_0$, is a (square-integrable) martingale.

Comment: Hello @John Dawkins, great answer, many thanks! I didn't expect a proper answer in this quality and so fast! You guys are great!^^

Answer (score 0):

You can show that, for any $t_1$ and $t_2$, where $0 \le t_1 < t_2 < T$,
\begin{align*}
E\left(\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{T-u}} dW_u \right) =0.
\end{align*}

Comment: This seems better suited for a comment than an answer..

Comment: @Math1000: from my observation, it is the style of this site. You can see many such answers or hints. On some other site, I also make comments like yours.